# How do i get "start" event data from fullcalendar js?

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, fullcalendar

I'm currently trying to mix both Bootstrap modal and FullCalendar. Here is what im trying right now.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // page is now ready, initialize the calendar...
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        // put your options and callbacks here
        displayEventTime: true,

        events : [

            {
                title : 'event2',
                start : '2017-12-27',
                end : '2017-12-27'
            },
        ],
        eventClick:  function(event, jsEvent, view) {
            var dt = event.start;
            alert('Event Clicked on : ' + dt);
            $('#modalTitle').html(event.title);
            $('#modalBody').html(event.dt);
            $('#modalTimePerformance').html(event.description);
            //$('#eventUrl').attr('href',event.url);
            $('#fullCalModal').modal();
        }

    })
});
```

Here is the bootstrap modal html

```
<div id="fullCalModal" class="modal fade">
<div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span aria-hidden="true">×</span> <span class="sr-only">close</span></button>
            <h4 id="modalTitle" class="modal-title"></h4>
            <h4 id="modalTimePerformance"></h4>
        </div>
        <div id="modalBody" class="modal-body"></div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

i tried putting the event.start inside #modalBody, it but it does not show up, so i tried doing an alert to see what it actually gets from the data, when i do alert "dt", it gives "Event Clicked on : 1514332800000".

Anyone has tried doing this before ?

Comment: `event.dt` is probably not defined. its either `dt` or `event.start`

Comment: @JonasW. i did event.start before this, it does not show up, thats why i did var dt = event.start just to see the alert but it returns that long integer, in this case: 1514332800000

Comment: I assume you don't like the format. You can always format it. `moment(dt).format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss')` is probably more understandable. That will result in 2017-12-27 02:00:00 given dt is your 1514332800000.